# Perserving newline characters in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to create an Excel file using PHPExcel. The source data is an array of associative arrays, each of which stores a name and address:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Joe Bloggs
            [address] => 10 Main St 
Bayside 
Big Town ABC123
    )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mary Bloggs
            [address] => 18 Bridge St
Riverside
Small Town XYZ987
        )
    :
    :
)
```

As you can see, the addresses contain newline characters. I am writing this data to an Excel file using PHP using the following code:

```
$phpExcel = new PHPExcel();

$phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue("Name");
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->setValue("Address");
$index = 2;
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$index)->setValue($row["name"]);
    $phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$index)->setValue($row["address"]);
    $index++;
}
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, 'Excel2007');
$filename = "outputs/excel/data.xlsx";
$objWriter->save($filename);
```

However, the resulting Excel file does not contain the newline characters, which I want to preserve.

```
Name         Address
Joe Bloggs   10 Main St Bayside Big Town ABC123
Mary Bloggs  18 Bridge St Riverside Small Town XYZ987
...
```

From [comments](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/225257) in the PHPExcel website, it seems that it should be possible to do this, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Can anyone help me? THANKS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use "\n" as the return character; and a cell needs to be set to `wrap`;

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('A1')
    ->setValue("First line\nSecond Line\nThird Line");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setWrapText(true);
```

as described in section 4.6.6 of the developer documentation

Answer (score 7):

Try using this instead of "\n":

```
$lfcr = chr(10) . chr(13);
```

then replace "\n" everywhere with $lfcr, like this:

```
setValue("First line". $lfcr . "second Line" . $lfcr . "Third Line");
```